# Need to send Email when a particular cell is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google spreadsheet.

I have Email addresses of participants in A column, and their corresponding Status in B column.( The status will be either, YES or NO or MAY BE or empty).

If B5 value is updated, then I need to send email to address in A5 with new value. The email should send only to A5 if the cell B5 is updated. Similary the email should send to A6 only if B6 is updated.

I have tried various options, searched for it, but couldnot able to find the solution. Please help me with that.

Thanks,

MAKS

Comment: javascript doesn't send emails. You'll need to use a service, like one of Google's API's or your own server to send an email.

Comment: Thanks  Adeneo for the answer. Yes I am using Google API for sending the email. I am able to send the email based on particular value in the cell. But I need to know how to send the email based on the value change in the spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

An `onEdit()` trigger function will be invoked when the contents of any cell in your spreadsheet is edited. You can find [plenty of examples of such functions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20is:question%20onedit) here in StackOverflow.

Unfortunately, as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple), that type of trigger function will not be able to send an email, or do any other operation that requires user authentication.